# Stacked geom_area with multiple row data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a stacked area plot. My data looks like below:

```
data <- structure(list(value = c(3.84, 5.21, 51.16, 0, 7.58, 1.81, 6.74, 
28.27, 6.49, 5.9, 6.15, 0.08, 26.23, 23.76, 24.68, 19.97, 2.89, 
2.84, 4.05, 18.24, 46.83, 30.47, 29.17, 0, 0.15, 0.23, 29.18, 
24.24, 38.58, 21.82, 33.85, 27.23, 27.91, 30.03, 75.12, 5.25, 
6.02, 6.1, 8.62, 81.01, 23.97, 27.99, 19.64, 57.61, 22.22, 19.76, 
18.05, 36.94, 29.13, 20.75, 26.07), category = c("C", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "C", "C", "A", "C", "C", "C", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C", 
"C", "A", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "C"), date = structure(c(17041, 
17041, 17042, 17042, 17042, 17042, 17042, 17043, 17043, 17043, 
17043, 17044, 17044, 17044, 17044, 17044, 17044, 17044, 17044, 
17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17046, 17046, 
17046, 17046, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17048, 17048, 17048, 
17048, 17048, 17049, 17049, 17049, 17049, 17050, 17050, 17050, 
17050, 17051, 17051, 17051, 17051), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-51L))
```

I have tried the following

```
data %>% ggplot() + geom_area(aes(date, value, fill = category), position = 'stack')
```

but this gives me:
[image]

I have also tried adding `stat = 'sum'` but it doesn't work neither. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not 100 % sure if it provides correct output - please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have messy data like this, it's best to do the data manipulation yourself outside of `ggplot`. In order to get an area plot, you need to collapse multiple observations per day into 1 value and include zeros for days where there are no observations. You can do this with

```
data %>% 
  mutate(category=factor(category)) %>% 
  group_by(date, category) %>% 
  summarize_all(sum) %>% 
  tidyr::complete(date, category, fill=list(value=0)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, value, fill=category)) + 
    geom_area(position="stack")
```

[image]